# model binding how collect data from <div>

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have model

`public class MyModel
{
  public string Name { get; set;}
}`

I have html code

```
<div id="Name">Important data</div>
```

In Controller, i have a method

```
public ActionResult Index (MyModel model)
{
    model.Name == "Important data"
}
```

Is it real, using standart model binder? thx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The model binder parses request data into objects. When you use a `div` there's no request data, nothing posted to the server. You could use a form with input fields in order to send request parameters that could be handled by the model binder and converted into object:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <div id="name"><%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name) %></div>
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
<% } %>
```

Or use an anchor:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("send to server", "index", new { Name = "some name to send" }) %>
```

Another option would be to send the request using AJAX:

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/home/index',
        data: { name: $('#name').html() },
        success: function(result) {
            alert('success');
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: or, if you just want the name displayed but not editable, include a hidden input field within your DIV that contains the value of "Name".